# How to inject dependency into MVC action using Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have seen implementations of .NET CORE MVC utilizing MVC action injection rather than using it in the controller constructor.

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and MVC v5.2.6.0

Is there a way to do it using Unity?

Comment: Reference [Dependency injection into controllers in ASP.NET Core: Action Injection with FromServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#action-injection-with-fromservices)

Comment: Are you asking for Core or previous version of asp.net-mvc? What platform are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi thats what I need but without .NET Core and using Unity. I have updated the question.